# Eclipse pdt not launching after update

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

Hi i had check for updates in Eclipse, and after the update i have this message:
"An error has occured. See log file".

And this is the log file: http://dev.edandweb.co.il/myError.log
I did this update just for solve an other problem, when i was type $this-> eclipse wasn't auto complete with existing methods.

I search in the forum for same topics, but i think that this error type depends on the message and he's different for every one.

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Right, so basically nothing works :) You seem to be getting errors reported from almost every plugin. Those are hard to pinpoint the reason for, so I'd start with a revert of the last install, See http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-123.htm
Then try to install it again to make sure it wasn't a temporary issue with the installation.

Comment: Thank you !
But i can't access to Eclipse, when i have the error message, i click ok and the program don't start. So i can't do the revert of the installation.